# Get previous value from column A when column B is not null in Hive

Tags: hive, null, lag

I have a table `tableA` below

```
ID   number   Estimate   Client    
----   ------
1      3          8         A 
1      NULL       10        Null
1      5          11        A      
1      NULL       19        Null 
2      NULL       20        Null
2      2          70        A   
.......
```

I would like to select previous row of `Estimate` column when `number` column is not null. For instance, when `number = 3`, then `pre_estimate = NULL`, when `number = 5`, then `pre_estimate = 10`, and when `number = 2`, then `pre_estimate = 20`.

The query below does not seem to return the correct answer in Hive. What should be correct way to do it?

```
select lag(Estimate, 1) OVER (partition by ID) as prev_estimate
from tableA
where number is not null
```

Comment: Your table has no column that defines the ordering of the rows, so the notion of "previous" row is unclear.

Comment: @GMB what would be an example of that ordering column? Can I add one and then do the lag operation to find the previous row?

Comment: `lag(Estimate, 1) OVER (partition by ID order by some_col) as prev_estimate`. Here some_col is what GMB is mentioning. You need to find it out. Form your data its not clear.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Is there any requirement regarding this some_col? I do have a timestamp column which can be ordered by. But I tried that as well, so give null value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the table with following structure:

```
number - int
estimate - int
order_column - int
```

`order_column` is taken as a column on which you want to sort your table rows.

Data in table:

```
number   estimate   order_column
3          8         1 
NULL       10        2
5          11        3      
NULL       19        4 
NULL       20        5
2          70        6
```

I used the following query and got the result you have mentioned.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT number, estimate, lag(estimate,1) over(order by order_column) as prev_estimate from tableA) tbl where tbl.number is not null;
```

As per my understanding, I didn't find the reason to partition by id, that's why I haven't considered ID in the table.

The reason you were getting wrong results is due to the reason that where clause in main query will select only the records with number as not null and then it computes lag function, but you need to consider all the rows when computing the lag function and then you should select rows with number as not null.